# How to print on already printed paper from a webpage?

Tags: php, html, css, printing

i have already printed pages of A4 size in printer image is attached!
now i want to print data in blank fields from webpage any one guide me how to achieve this?

i want to put data exactly to those places to print receipt

[image: a4size receipt]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i ended up this issue using crystal reports with a windows application on dotnet, that has very beautiful and user friendly interface, php was not helping in this.

Answer (score 6):

Provide precise printing instructions by offering a PDF file in DIN-A4 format.

You can generate the PDF with various PDF libraries from your PHP script.

Comment: +1 this - PDF is the only way to reliably control print areas through (current) widely available web technologies

Comment: could you please provide me steps, its bit confusing, let suppose i have data on php page from where to start?

Comment: Newer browsers are a *little* better than they were, but PDF is going to be far more reliable. And even then, you can't guarantee that it will print correctly, as the user's printer configuration (options like scaling and automatic margin adjustments) cannot be controlled from the browser. If this is for an internal application, where you control the printer setup etc, then you could look at a css solution, but otherwise (as others have said) you're best off with a PDF and instructions on how to turn off scaling etc

Answer (score 0):

You can specify all CSS elements in centimeters or inches  This is especially useful if you use a @media = print

So, you could have something like:

```
<div id="booking_num" style="position: absolute; top: 6.25cm;left:2.32in;">
  1213123
</div>
```

This has been working very reliably on any modern browsers.

Comment: will it work for different screen resolutions? according to my research people dont recommend to print a4 size using this way because on each screen this size will differ there is some role of dpi.

Comment: @umar I thought this was for print.  The problem with screen is not just DPI but more importantly zoom, even on PDF documents.  This will work for the default zoom just fine, but the best way to test it is to do some trial runs.